# Directories owned by user 501 after migrating between MacBooks and changing users

Tags: homebrew, permission, user-account

I set up a new Macbook using the migration assistant. As I wanted to keep the name of my user directory on the old machine, and this was attached to an account I migrated as part of the process, I did some renaming on the user directories so that my new main user ended up with the old user's directory name. After that, I deleted the account I had migrated. This appears to have created a bit of chaos in directory ownership, as shown in a small example here (just a random example of a location with exactly three directories demonstrating all three states existing on my system):

```
❯ cd /opt
❯ ls -l
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   9 root      wheel   288  3 Nov  2016 X11
drwxr-xr-x  33 <myuser>  admin  1056 17 Sep 18:20 homebrew
drwxr-xr-x   3 501       staff    96 22 Jan  2017 homebrew-cask
```

`root:wheel` appears to be the default.

I changed the `homebrew` directory to my current user manually today, as Hombrew was having some issues and this directory previously also belonged to `501:staff`.

The last line shows the case where there are directories left with `501:staff`. After some initial research, it seems to me that these are directories that would have been migrated from my old Macbook, where they still belonged to the main admin account there. After deleting that user (see intro above), they were assigned to `501:staff`.

1. Is this understanding correct?
2. How should such a state be handled in order to ensure a proper setup for the new system? I am expecting more issues down the road when the system wants to make modifications to these locations. Is there a safe way to change all ownership for these directories?

I am also a bit confused by the fact that I can find neither `<myuser>` nor `501` in
`/etc/passwd`. (Should I?)

Comment: Maybe this will be of use? https://eclecticlight.co/2023/08/23/ignoring-ownership-and-501-orphans/ I don't fully understand the problem you're outlining in the OP, but there seem to be some parallels.

Comment: The `501` is the UID.  You only see the UID displayed because you deleted the user associated with it, which did not remove or change ownership on any directories created with that UID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, when you did the migration, the migrated account was created with the user ID number 501, and the migrated files were assigned to that user. When you deleted the account, the files got orphaned -- on the volume, they're listed as being owned by uid #501, but that no longer corresponds to any existing account, so `ls` just displays the raw uid number.

You can transfer ownership of any files inside a directory that're still assigned to the orphaned uid to your new account with:

```
sudo find -x /opt -uid 501 -exec chown yournewusername {} +
```

(After replacing `yournewusername` with your actual new username, that is.)

Note that this doesn't just change ownership of the top-level folder, it also changes any files anywhere inside it that're still owned by 501 (as long as the're on the same volume -- I recommend `-x` to avoid it accidentally going wild). This is preferred over just using `chown -R` since that'll change ownership of *everything*, including files that should be owned by root, etc. Also, you can replace `/opt` with any other directory you want to scan for orphaned files.

As for /etc/passwd: macOS doesn't use that except for very early in the boot process; after that it uses the "directory services" database, which is completely separate. You can look up users with the `id` command (or if you want to spend some time reading man pages, `dscacheutil` or `dscl`).

BTW, you can use `ls -ln` to see the numeric user IDs (and group IDs) listed for *all* files, including for accounts that exist. If you'd run it on that same directory (before making any changes), it'd have looked like this:

```
❯ ls -ln
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   9 0    0    288  3 Nov  2016 X11
drwxr-xr-x  33 502  80  1056 17 Sep 18:20 homebrew
drwxr-xr-x   3 501  20    96 22 Jan  2017 homebrew-cask
```

Where uid #502 is your new user account uid #0 is root, and 0, 20, and 80 are the group IDs of wheel, staff, and admin respectively.